# I have issues with saving my script in R x64 on my windows 10 pc, with crashing etc

Tags: r, save, rstudio

Every time I work on a script in R I come across the problem, that R isn't able to save my script, although I don't use problematic file names and put an .R in the name. I get an error message where the pathname is displayed, as to show me that there is a problem with that. I tried copy-pasting my script into a new one, but the problem persists with the new script file. Furthermore, when I try to copy the text and paste it after having restarted R (the console), it does not work. The scripts, the original one which has stayed blank, as saving did not work, or a new blank one, stay blank when trying to past text.
I should add that R seems to crash when it tries to save the original script that is not savable. When I close the console, R warns me that I have not saved the script, so I press on save before closing. Then R seems to save it, but ultimately crashes.
Later on, I realized that the copy-pasting does not work on my computer at all. I think this problem only started from the moment on I could not save my script in R.

I would be grateful for support from the community.
I'll have an exam where we need to upload our script, so I really need the saving to work.

Greetings,

J.C.

Comment: Sadly, there is nothing anyone can say with certainty here. R crashing is certainly a problem, but it is not clear if you mean R or RStudio crashing. Additionally, saving a text file is not something that is risky for any IDE, RStudio included, so is it saving it or evaluating it that is causing the crash? Some precautionary steps: if you have a `.Rdata` file in your project or home directories, move it out of the way; they are often problematic anyway, it's usually best to not auto-load them. After that, restart R and RStudio and try again. Good luck.

Comment: (I'm inferring [tag:rstudio], by the way. If you're using "just plain `Rterm`", forgive me, we can remove the tag.)